# IP Admin url returning 404 error after succesfull installaion

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, theme, frontend, backend

Deployed magento on linux machine. I cant able to access `front-end` and admin after successful installation.

store ip:  http://52.187.32.74/rahhams

store admin ip:  http://52.187.32.74/rahhams/admin_msp8sn

Php version: 7.0.

Comment: what errors you are getting?check under var/report folder.

Comment: There is no folder in the name report , still default files exception.log and system.log are not created.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem please, why can't you access it? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get proper work admin, you need to enable rewrite module by command

```
a2enmod rewrite from ubuntu and then 

sudo service apache2 restart

and if not working go to path /etc/apache2/ and edit file apache2.conf

use command  sudo gedit  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and changed line

<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>

to 


<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>


Now run command 

sudo service apache2 restart
```